# Create a WCF Service Implemented by Third Party

Tags: .net, wcf, web-services

I need to create the web service API and data contracts for a webservice that will be hosted by my company but will be implemented by a third-party.  What's the best way to do that?

Ideally, I don't want to require the third-party to have to use .NET or any particular technology.  I just want to give them the operation and data contracts.

Comment: But then they have to create the host project and use the operation and data contracts that we provided?  What if they don't use .NET at all?

Comment: If they're creating the service for you to use (and for you to maintain), then you should **definitely** specify which technology they must  use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**IF** your third-party **uses .NET** - then the easiest solution would be to just simply define the contracts as interfaces in C# or VB.NET - the **service contract**, the **operation contracts** (service methods), the **data contracts** (types being passed back and forth) - but leave the implementation up to the third-party.

You can stick all this into a separate class library assembly and just ship them that assembly as your API definition, basically. That third-party can then implement the **service implementation** as a C#/VB.NET class library, and ship it back to you.

**IF** your third-party **does not use .NET** at all, then you have to create a **WSDL** (Web Service Description Language) document that describes the service and its methods, and some **XSD** (XML schema) files that describe the data types being sent back and forth.

You can do this fairly easily by basically doing the same steps as above - create your service, operations and data contracts - and then implementing a "dummy" implementation of that service yourself; then spin up that service and create the WSDL / XSD from that running service. Ship those documents to your third-party to have them implement the service per se.

Or of course - you can also author the WSDL/XSD manually, from scratch - but that borders on a) black art and b) masochism - not recommended ...

Comment: Ok, so we generate the WSDL and XSD, then they implement the service.  Then we have to implement the client to that service, I'm assuming I can't use the generate service reference in Visual Studio for that - unless they have a version of the service up and running?

Comment: In your svc.vb file markup each method with <WebMethod()>, then add a .asmx file (contents just like .svc file), when you hit .asmx?wsdl you get a traditional WSDL.

Comment: @jjm340: you can generate your service client (a) either from the WSDL/XSD files you've created, or (b) from the implemented service once it's up and running - your choice.